# Linq method - Return rows only found in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, linq-method-syntax

I want to return the Tags from the Tag table that are only found in the TagRecipe table. How can I do this?

```
            var dataTags = await _context.Tags
                .Include(tc => tc.TagCategory)
                .ToListAsync();
```

```
    public class Tag
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TagRecipe> TagRecipes { get; set; }

        public int TagCategoryID { get; set; }
        public TagCategory TagCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class TagRecipe
    {
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public Tag Tag { get; set; }
        public Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Could you pls post both table  model s Tag and TagRecipe?

Comment: No problem, done.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 var dataTags = await _context.TagRecipe
                .Include(tc => tc.Tag.TagCategory)
                .Select(i=> i.Tag)
                .ToListAsync();
```

or you can use this syntax if you like it more

```
var dataTags = await _context.TagRecipe
                .Include(t => t.Tag)
                .ThenInclude(tc => tc.TagCategory)
                .Select(i=> i.Tag)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Serge: I believe you're missing a `.Distinct`. Imagine  a case where join table `TagRecipe` contains 5 records with TagId = 1.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative starting at table **Tags** using `Join` that will return a result without duplicates.

```
var dataTags = db.Tags
    .Join(db.TagRecipes, tag => tag.Id, tagRecipe => tagRecipe.TagId, (tag, tagRecipe) => tag)
    .Include(tag => tag.TagCategory)
    .ToLookup(tag => tag.Id) // client-side from here
    .Select(grouping => grouping.First()) // to make distinct
    .ToList();
```

Will generate a straight-forward SQL

```
SELECT "t"."Id", "t"."Name", "t"."TagCategoryId", "t1"."Id", "t1"."Name"
FROM "Tags" AS "t"
INNER JOIN "TagRecipes" AS "t0" ON "t"."Id" = "t0"."TagId"
INNER JOIN "TagCategories" AS "t1" ON "t"."TagCategoryId" = "t1"."Id"
```

It is possible to use `.Distinct` in the above expression for removing duplicates instead of using grouping, but that will create a more complex SQL.

Table *TagRecipes* seems to be a join table in a many-to-many between table **Tags** and table **Recipes**. The latter is not included in the question, but I added it during my tests.

Please note that in EF Core 5, *many-to-many* relations may be created without an entity class for the join table.